# Write coordinates to file from 4 numpy arrays Python

Tags: python, file, numpy

There are 4 numpy matrices,for exemple, 3x3 with coordinates:

```
Xg [[-0.5  0.3  1.1]
    [-0.5  0.3  1.1]
    [-0.5  0.3  1.1]]

Yg [[-0.5 -0.5 -0.5]
    [ 0.3  0.3  0.3]
    [ 1.1  1.1  1.1]]

 u [[ 1.  1.  1.]
    [ 1.  1.  1.]
    [ 1.  1.  1.]]

 v [[ 1.03793  0.25065 -0.28944]
    [-0.21591 -0.93072 -0.10047]
    [-0.08591 -0.11284 -0.06082]]
```

How I can write coordinates in file like this:

```
# in file should be ", {{" x_coordinate","y_coordinate"},{"u_coordinate","v_coordinate"}}")
 file = open("coordinates.txt", "w")
 file.write(",{{" + x + "," + y + "},{" + u + "," + v + "}}")

 #Output
  ,{{-0.5,-0.5},{1,1.03793}}, {{0.3,-0.5},{1,0.25065}}, {{1.1,-0.5},{1,-0.28944}},...
```

Comment: what do you mean with "next way"?

Comment: does `numpy.savetxt` not do what you're after? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html

Comment: my english is not so good i mean "like this" when said "next way"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do nested for loops, like this:

```
 X = [[-0.5, 0.3, 1.1],
      [-0.5, 0.3, 1.1],
      [-0.5, 0.3, 1.1]]

Y = [[-0.5, -0.5, -0.5],
      [0.3, 0.3, 0.3],
      [1.1, 1.1, 1.1]]

U = [[1, 1, 1, ],
     [1, 1, 1, ],
     [1, 1, 1, ]]

V = [[1.03793, 0.25065, -0.28944],
     [-0.21591, -0.93072, -0.10047],
     [-0.08591, -0.11284, -0.06082]]

with open("coordinates.txt", "w") as f:
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            f.write("{{{0},{1}}}, {{{2}, {3}}}\n".format(X[j][i], Y[j][i],  U[j][i], V[j][i]))
```

Which gives

```
{-0.5,-0.5}, {1, 1.03793}
{-0.5,0.3}, {1, -0.21591}
{-0.5,1.1}, {1, -0.08591}
{0.3,-0.5}, {1, 0.25065}
{0.3,0.3}, {1, -0.93072}
{0.3,1.1}, {1, -0.11284}
{1.1,-0.5}, {1, -0.28944}
{1.1,0.3}, {1, -0.10047}
{1.1,1.1}, {1, -0.06082}
```

Comment: That's right, but its necessary, that {{x,y},{u,v}} will be in brackets  { {},{} }

Comment: I've updated the formatting to match, you can mess around with it more to get exactly what you want.

Comment: It's great! Thank you!

Comment: If it's helpful don't forget to give it an upvote :)

Comment: Oh, one more question: when I add new { } , appears 
" Single '}' encountered in format string" error. What's happend?

Comment: For single brackets you want to double them, so {{...}}

Comment: I want add outer brackets { {x,y},{u,v} }

Comment: `{{{{{0},{1}}}, {{{2}, {3}}}}}`